# How to get wxmenu pointer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wxwidgets

I just want to get wxmenu pointer which in created in different class  , like how  we are getting window using wxwindowbyname(). could you please help me out of this. 
Is there any static function in widgets to get popupmenu pointer at time we can popup only one thing only right.i am using wxmenus in N number of classes I cant we use N number of function in N class for getting pointer again checking N number of thing in main this annoying.

Answer (score 0):

If class A contains a wxMenu pointer, you can provide a method that return your pointer:

```
 class A {
   public:
     inline wxMenu* menu() { return menu_; }
   private:
     wxMenu* menu_;
 }
```

In your main, or wherever you want:

```
int main() {
   A* a = new A();
   wxMenu* menu = a->menu();
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the currently shown popup menu if this is what your question is about. If you need to keep track of it, you have to do it yourself, i.e. remember the menu you're showing before showing it.

Usually there should be really no need to do this though, why do you think you need it?

Comment: why I need is while working on my exe manually , I just recording all events(control ids ,event type) , next time I just playing recorded thing , it works based in top window &event id using these two I am posting the events. some how I am getting top window but I was struck at popupmenu , I just thinking how get shown popupmenu .